# MinGW gcc C compiler works, but g++ does not

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, mingw32

I'm a noob, I admit it.  Regardless, I've had a really annoying problem with MinGW....  I can write AND compile programs in C with no problem whatsoever, but recently I've tried to install Cmake, but I can't because it fails every time it tests the C++ compiler (g++).  So that lead me to just write a simple "hello world" program in C++ and try to compile it.  No dice.  Again and again I get no response whatsoever.  On the command line, I'm typing

```
g++ -o hello++.cpp hello++
```

but have also tried

```
g++ -o hello++.cxx hello++
g++ -o hello++.cc hello++
g++ -o hello++ hello++.cpp
```

(Of course I saved copies of the source code in the same directory with the .cxx and .cc extensions respectively)

and a bunch of other combinations thereof.  Everytime I get nothing.  No warning.  No error.  Nothing.  No .exe file was created in the directory, and typing "hello++" on the command line afterwards just gives me a "command not found" error.  Soooo.... what the hell is going on?  Why does the gcc command work but the g++ not?

I'm on windows 8, using cygwin.

Comment: To start with, only one of those commands is correct, and that is the last one (`g++ -o hello++ hello++.cpp`). I don't like to have screenshots of text, but in this case I would really like to see a screenshot of you running that command, followed by a `dir` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last one should have succeeded; you won't get a message saying it's succeeded, but you should see the executable in the current directory. The others all try to take the executable as input and output the source, which won't work; although I'm surprised you don't get error messages.

If it did succeed, then simply typing `hello++` is unlikely to run it since the current directory is typically not on the path. Try `./hello++` instead.

If it didn't succeed, then it's possible that `g++` isn't installed properly. I'm afraid I've no idea how to fix a broken Cygwin installation. Perhaps `which g++`, to see which program is actually being run, might give some clues.

Comment: Thanks Mike, although it seems the latter may be the case, I tried your suggestions, the one about adding "./" in front was useful, but still gave an error, "no such file or directory".  I was wondering something though, if g++ isn't installed correctly, wouldn't trying to compile something with it produce an error message? Because at current, it doesn't.  So that made me think that maybe the output file could be being redirected to some other directory..... but honestly I don't know if that's even possible, soo... is it?

Comment: You were right, it was a bad install.  I uninstalled MinGW, deleted all of its files, re downloaded and installed from scratch, and lo and behold, both gcc and g++ work now.